# How to move mouse between 4 monitors

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have 4 monitors which works fine

[image]

The issue I have is moving the mouse cursor between:

1. Screen 2 and 4
2. Screen 2 and 1

What I'd like is to have

[image]

This shows I could move the mouse from the left side of screen 2 direct into screen 4. It also shows that I can move from the right side screen 2 into screen 1. Other than these 2 changes, the rest would work as normal.

Is this possible in Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only traverse screens where that pictorial representation shows adjacent areas - no matter how that representation matches your physical screen sizes [or even locations].

The OS cannot tell how big each screen is, only what resolution it is - so that 'map' is the only way it can know to pass the cursor over.

Based on that - there is no way to pass from 2 to either 4 or 1.

Comment: Whilst I agree with your answer, it doesn't seem impossible. I mean, the cursour doesn't leave the left or right side of a single monitor - so the OS does know where the boundaries are.? As such, I wonder if a script that detects if the cursor is against the edge and moves the cursor automatically... I will look at AHK